# Ramda - partially applied function depends on full application

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I have a situation where the value that I want to add depends on a future value i.e.

```
let metadata = {videoId: 123, likes: 400};
let addSubtitles = R.assoc('subtitles', R.__, R.__);
```

Here `addSubtitles` is a partially applied function. However, the second argument of `addSubtitles` is supposed to be the subtitles, but the subtitles themselves depend on the third argument i.e. `metadata.videoId`. To be called as follows:

```
addSubtitles(metadata); //but with another argument perhaps?
const subtitles = async getSubtitles(videoId) => await apiCall(videoId);
```

Any way to solve this in a functional manner? It seems possible if I were to bound the context of the future third argument, but unsure of how to go about doing this.

Please let me know if there is any extra information needed to answer.

This is a working solution, though I was looking to use Ramda to make this work:

```
const addSubs = async function(el) {¬
  const subtitles = await writeCaptions(el.videoId);¬
  return R.assoc('subtitles', subtitles, el);¬
};
```

Comment: I'm not really following the question, perhaps because I need to go to bed.  But one comment is that `R.assoc('subtitles', R.__, R.__)` is no different from `R.assoc('subtitles', R.__)`, which itself is no different from `R.assoc('subtitles')`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Thanks for taking a look; my question is likely unclear. I edited the question to add a solution that works for the purpose, but I was looking for a Ramda-specific solution. Let me know if that clears it up.

Answer (score 2):

First let me back up a moment to note that you don't need to use `R._` for later values in the signature. Almost every function in the Ramda libary is auto-curried for you, so you can call with all arguments or just some subset to preload data. `R._` is only used for holding a space for future calls.

So what you want to do with currying is just keep adding parameters one at a time until you get a complete function ready to call. When the order is wrong you can use `R.flip` or `R._` (depending on context) to reach the values you are ready to fill, and come back to the values you don't know yet.

So from your description, it sounds like your concern is that `getSubtitles(metadata)` is a network call that returns a promise. This example will proceed under that assumption. Here I think `R.flip` will be more expressive for you than `R._`.

```
const  metadata = { videoId: 123, likes: 400 }

const addSubtitles = R.flip(R.assoc('subtitles'))
// Now you have a curried function that takes 2 arguments, first the metadata, and then the subtitles.

const withSubtitlesPromise = getSubtitles(metadata)
  // Here we drill down a little further by adding the metadata, and then
  // pass it as the callback to .then, which will pass in the final param
  // once it resolves
  .then(addSubtitles(metadata)

withSubtitlesPromise.then(console.log)
```

You could definitely capture all of this logic in a single function that takes in `metadata` and returns a promise for subtitled data. For good measure, we'll also pass in `getSubtitles` as a depenedency, for easier testing and weaker coupling. Now it's trivial to swap out another function for retrieving subtitle data. In this case, the use of `R._` makes the code a little cleaner, so we'll switch it up.

```
// Define all the logic in a single easy function
const makeAddSubtitles = getSubtitles => metadata =>
  getSubtitles(metadata).then(R.assoc('subtitles', R._, metadata))

// Then push in the dependency
const addSubtitles = makeAddSubtitles(getSubtitles)

// Use it
const vid123 = { videoId: 123, likes: 400 }
const vid123WithSubsPromise = addSubtitles(vid123)
```

Comment: thank you for this answer. it makes a lot of sense, the only differentiating factor is that the subtitle function in my question depends on a property of the metadata itself. I updated the question to better reflect that with a potential solution. Though your answer leads me to believe that my solution is the only way (I was looking for a ramda-specific answer)

Comment: Read through the example again. I think you're missing it. The "working solution" you added simplifies to `const addSubs = el => writeCaptions(el.videoId).then(R.assoc('subtitles', R._, el))`